Satisfiability to graph isomorphism reduction
$\text{GI} = \{\langle A, B \rangle∶  \text{ graph A is isomorphic to graph B} \}$
I want to reduce from, $\text{3SAT}\leq_p \text{GI}.$
I know how to reduce from  GI to SAT: Whenever we see two graphs that have an unequal number of vertices or edges, output any unsatisfiable formula.
Now suppose we have two graphs A and B, each with n vertices labeled 0 through n-1, and each with the same number of edges. Output a formula with n^2 variables that encodes the statement "there is an isomorphism between these two graphs". Here's how to construct such a formula:
Our variables will be denoted x[i,j]. The intention is that each valid assignment of truth values to x[i,j] will correspond to one isomorphism between A and B. More precisely, x[i,j] will be true iff vertex i in graph A corresponds to vertex j in graph B in that particular isomorphism.
Our formula will contain the following clauses:

for each i: exactly one of x[0,j], x[1,j], ..., x[n-1,j] is true
for each j: exactly one of x[i,0], x[i,1], ..., x[i,n-1] is true
for each a,b such that A contains the edge ab, and for each c,d such that B does not contain the edge cd: at most one of x[a,c] and x[b,d] is true.

But when I try to prove $\text{3SAT}\leq_p \text{GI}$, my mind doesn't working, would anyone help me how to proceed?

The graph isomorphism problem is not known to be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.
It is unlikely that someone has a proof of that.

Oh, I see. It was unknown to me. Thanks.

If we have given that GI is NPC then in this case, how to prove the reduction? Would you give me the way?

I don't understand what your question means… "If we assume we know the answer to this unknown question, how do we prove it?" is exactly what I understand.

I mean, suppose if we have given GI is NPC then 3SAT to GI reduction possible?

You cannot construct a reduction that is not known to exist EVEN IF you suppose it exists…

I suggest you pick a book or something and work on the different definitions about $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$-completeness from scratch.
